# Determine for what values of x the sequence fn(x) = (nx+5)/(6n+7) converges pointwise

Tags: real-analysis

May you tell me if this reasoning is correct? Thank you so much!

fn(x) = (nx+5)/(6n+7)

***Determine for what values of x the sequence converges pointwise.***

The limit function f(x) = x/6

D(x)= Absolute value of (fn(x) - f(x))

= Absolute value of ((nx+5)/(6n+7) - x/6)

= Absolute value of (30-7x)/(36n+42)

The limit of D(x) when n goes to infinite is 0, for all values of x.

***D(x) is the distance function between fn(x) and f(x).***

Thus fn(x) converges uniformly for all values of R, and for that reason it converges pointwise for all R.

Comment: You have to speak of uniformly convergent on some AREA but not for points. So e.g. uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. You above proof with the distance function shows pointwise convergent for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is pointwise convergence, your proof is correct. An easier way is the following: $$f_n(x) = \frac{n(x+5/n)}{n(6+7/n)} = \frac{x+5/n}{6+7/n} \to \frac{x}{6} \ \ (n \to \infty)$$
But the sequence is not uniformly convergent: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for $x=-36N-42$ and $n \geq N$ we have

$$f_n(x)-f(x) = \frac{30-7(-36N-42)}{36n+42} = \frac{30}{36n+42}+7 > 7$$

Thus for e.g. $\epsilon=1$, the condition "$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$" is not true and $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Your ideas are wonderful! May you explain me how to calculate the supremum of D(x)? I am sure that I am confused with that. Thank you for everything!

Comment: For $D(x)$ its better to write $D_n(x)$ because it's the distance between two functions and one depends on n. But $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} D_n(x) = \infty$ since you can make the $x$ large and then $D_n(x)$ becomes large (because the $x$ is in the denominator of the above fraction)

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help! One new question: why did you write x is in the denominator? A typo? x is the numerator.

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo. Numerator is right ;)